# Change SharedPreference Value with Button

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I try to pass data from Activity to its fragment, using SharedPreference, and change the values of SharedPreference using button. 
Here is my code.

```
teesWhite = findViewById(R.id.tees_white)
    teesWhite!!.setOnClickListener {
        setWarna(R.drawable.wf, R.drawable.wb)
        teesColor!!.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_color_white)

    }
    teesBlack = findViewById(R.id.tees_black)
    teesBlack!!.setOnClickListener {
        setWarna(R.drawable.bf, R.drawable.bb)
        teesColor!!.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_color_black)

    }

 private fun setWarna(warnaDepan : Int, warnaBelakang : Int) {
    depan =  this.getSharedPreferences(resources.getString(R.string.app_name), Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val editor = depan!!.edit()
    editor.clear()
    editor.putInt(KAOS_DEPAN,warnaDepan)
    editor.putInt(KAOS_BELAKANG, warnaBelakang)
    editor.apply()
}
```

**EDIT**
SharedPreference is working and the value passed to fragment (I use the values to set Image Resource of an ImageView).

```
 kaosdepan = view.findViewById(R.id.kaosdepan)
    warnaKaos = activity!!.getSharedPreferences(resources.getString(R.string.app_name), Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val kaos = warnaKaos!!.getInt(KAOS_DEPAN,0)
    kaosdepan!!.setImageResource(kaos)
kaosbelakang = view.findViewById(R.id.kaosbelakang)
    val kaos2 = warnaKaos!!.getInt(KAOS_BELAKANG, 0)
    kaosbelakang!!.setImageResource(kaos2)
```

But buttons to change SharedPreference's value don't work. The ImageView never change.

Comment: How are you verifying that the change to shared preferences isn't changing? Something seems fishy with your use of `clear()` prior to setting the values. Also just for a tip `apply()` will perform the write asynchronously whereas a`commit` will do it on main thread (and return you a result of pass/fail). Please provide more context on the situation.

Comment: @BrandonMcAnsh I use the values to set Image Resource of an ImageView. Image's not changing when I clicked the button, so I think the value is not changed.
I add something on my thread above, pls check

Answer (score 0):

The activity context scope is not the same as the context scope of the fragment, therefore leading to inconsistent results of the getInt() calls. Either use `getDefaultSharedPreferences` or scope the SharedPreferences access through `applicationContext`

Comment: @Taufik did this help?